# Cannot delete partition

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning

I have the same trouble with an Acer Switch 10 with windows 8 that wouldn't boot after downloading updates.
I have gone through numerous attempts to no avail.
I first made a bootable USB stick that doesnt work.
It slowly gets to the stage where I have to delete the Partitions but will go no further.

The error is

> We couldn't delete the selected partition error 0x80070079

I have gone into Diskpart & did all the commands, List, Clean etc & cannot delete the partition also.
The error is

> The semaphore timeout period has expired.

I have gone through these procedures many times with the same result.
Have set the BIOS to boot from the USB & disabled secure Boot & changed many settings as possible & set them back to default.

Comment: Something to try: create a bootable Ubuntu install USB-stick (or DVD), boot it into "testing"-mode and when there; hit the windows key once, type `gparted` and double click it. Another alternative is `disks` - either of these two should be able to delete partitions - unless the disk itself is broken in some way. These OFTEN work when Windows-utils fails.

Comment: _The semaphore timeout period has expired_ maybe something else is using the position...

Comment: Microsoft stopped support for Windows 8 since 2016. What have you installed?

Comment: Have now tried GParted  & still cannot delete or format partitions so have given up & will chuck it in the bin as I have another identical one working fine,just wanted to get it going as a back up or maybe sell it.

Comment: It had Windows 8 installed but failed to boot after downloading updates

Comment: I might try Ubuntu later on, I'm low on data download at the moment as I've been downloading so many programs that have claimed to fix it & wasted my data & time. most of these programs show you how to do all these things but cant tell you where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting ALL partitions first.  Like this:

diskpart > list disk > select disk # (# is the disk number with partition you want gone) > clean

if that was already tried reinstalling windows might be the only option, assuming there is no hardware issue.

Comment: Trying to reinstall Windows was the original problem after downloading updates , bootable  USB wouldnt work, it got to the stage where I had to delete Partitions, that wouldnt work, tried programs that were supposed to delete, recover, partition etc.etc I cant even wipe it clean so I can install something. Thats why I have just about given up.